# Why isn't express-js setting the Content-Type header?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers, express, offline-caching

I have the following:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express.createServer();

app.get("/offline.manifest", function(req, res){
  res.contentType("text/cache-manifest");
  res.end("CACHE MANIFEST");
});

app.listen(8561);
```

The network tab in Chrome says it's `text/plain`. Why isn't it setting the header?

*The code above works, my problems were caused by a linking to an old version of express-js*

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`res.type('json')` works too now and as others have said, you can simply use
 `res.json({your: 'object'})`

Comment: this is great since it still allows you to use `res.send(obj)` to send objects as JSON. Better than `res.end(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: you can chain it too, `res.type('json').send({your: 'object'});` or as @danday74 below points out, simply `res.json({your: 'object'});`

Answer (score 24):

Try this code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express.createServer();

app.get("/offline.manifest", function(req, res){
  res.header("Content-Type", "text/cache-manifest");
  res.end("CACHE MANIFEST");
});

app.listen(8561);
```

(I'm assuming you are using the latest release of express, 2.0.0)

**UPDATE:**
I just did a quick test using Firefox 3.6.x and Live HTTP Headers. This is the addons output:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 X-Powered-By: Express
 Content-Type: text/cache-manifest
 Connection: keep-alive
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Make sure you clear your cache before trying.

Comment: i just tested it on my local development setup, worked perfectly (see update)

Comment: Aha! For some reason it was linking to an old version of node. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

instead of `res.send()`

use `res.json()` which automatically sets the content-type to `application/json`

Comment: this doesn't remotely answer the question

Comment: Not related to the question.

Comment: In my case, it was exactly the question : `Why isn't express-js setting the Content-Type header?` in my case to json. I learned about `res.json()`